# In Salesforce , why there is no OpportunityContactRole in schema builder ?

Tags: salesforce, apex

In Salesforce , why there is no OpportunityContactRole in schema builder ?
What is the relationship between opportunity and contact ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many-to-many relationship between Opportunity and Contact, through a junction object  alled OpportunityContactRole.

Please take a look at the [API Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitycontactrole.htm) and a detail explanation about the usage and limitation here: http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/04/what-is-opportunity-contact-role.html